# Prove that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}$ and $\vec{a}\times\vec{b} = \vec{a}\times\vec{c} \Rightarrow \vec{b} = \vec{c}$

Tags: linear-algebra

When I manipulate the first expression I get $$\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}-\vec{c})=0$$ implying that $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$.

For the second expression, I have been told I should "left multiply (in the vector sense) by $\vec{a}$."

Eventually I should be left with an expression that implies that $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ is parallel to $\vec{a}$, so that $\vec{b}-\vec{c}$ has to be the zero vector. I'm not sure how to manipulate the second expression after the multiplication to achieve this though?

Comment: Do you know the vector identity $\vec{u} \times (\vec{v} \times \vec{w}) = (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{w})\vec{v} - (\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{w}$? What is $\vec{a} \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{x})$?

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/213442/26872)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BAC-CAB rule.  Since the vectors you're given are themselves $a, b, c$, I'll write the identity in terms of three vectors $f, g, h$ to avoid confusion:

$$f \times (g \times h) = g (f \cdot h) - h (f \cdot g)$$

Applying this identity to $a \times (a \times b)$ yields $a (a \cdot b) - b |a|^2$.  You should be able to take it from here by using the same identity on $a, c$ instead.

Comment: Yeah I'd done that to both sides but I hadn't realised the significance. I think I understand it now actually; You get (a.(b-c))a on the other side. As the vectors a and b-c both have scalar coefficients, they must be parallel. Thus b-c must be the zero vector. Is that right?

Comment: @Mathlete unfortunately, in comments everything has to be on one line (since hitting enter submits the comment).

Comment: Sorry, I got that - please see my edited comment.

Comment: Yeah, basically.  The way I looked at it, you can reduce the expression down to $|a|^2 b = |a|^2 c$ (since you know the dot products were equal, they can be eliminated), but it's all basically the same idea.

Comment: Is it possible to show that geometrically?

Comment: Yeah, you can imagine $a \cdot b = a \cdot c$ defines a cone around the vector $a$.  $b, c$ must lie somewhere on this cone.  Knowing that their cross products are also equal tells us that $a, b$ and $a,c$ span the same plane.  Where this plane cuts the cone are the possible solutions for $b, c$. Enforcing that the cross products are equal (and not opposite) ensures that you conclude $b = c$.